# Adding argument to SELECT statement with UNION changes record number

Tags: sql, oracle

When I add a new argument to the `SELECT` clause of a `UNION`, I get more records... how can this be? Isn't a `UNION` just mashing them together? Example:

EDIT: They're absolutely distinct. the `code` column is either "IN" or "OUT", and that's what I'm using to separate the two.

EDIT2: UNION ALL gives me 80 records, like it should, but it's odd because my two SELECT statements are absolutely distinct.

FINAL EDIT: Ultimate problem was records within one of my SELECT statements being not DISTINCT, not between the two SELECT statements. Thanks all.

```
-- Yields 76 records
SELECT
       f.date
     , f.code
     , f.cost
  FROM a.fact f
  WHERE f.code = 'IN'
UNION
SELECT
       f2.date
     , f2.code
     , f2.cost
  FROM a.fact2 f2
  WHERE f2.code = 'OUT'
;

-- Yields 80 records
SELECT
       f.key
     , f.date
     , f.code
     , f.cost
  FROM a.fact f
  WHERE f.code = 'IN'
UNION
SELECT
       f2.key
     , f2.date
     , f2.code
     , f2.cost
  FROM a.fact2 f2
  WHERE f2.code = 'OUT'
;
```

Comment: how many records do you get from each select w/o the union?

Comment: Is key same data type in both tables?? And also non of the key(s) is/are null

Comment: also trim (key) ?? might be a char and varchar columns or spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default UNION selects distinct results, there must be duplicates between your result sets.

Comment: There definitively aren't.. sorry. The top `SELECT` has `WHERE code = 'IN'` and the bottom `SELECT` has `WHERE code = 'OUT'`

Comment: There could be duplicates within one of the result sets, for example if a.fact has two records with matching date, code and cost, but a different key.

Comment: That was the problem! The original developer didn't enforce a UNIQUE column, and I didn't think I needed to test something from 5 year old requirements.

Answer (score 5):

change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` and you should get the same results. `UNION` selects distinct rows, `UNION ALL` should select all.

Answer (score 0):

The `union all` will solve your problem, as mentioned in a previous answer, it selects the distinct values only

References [Oracle docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

Comment: @caleb.breckon I'm sure they are not in the first sql code

Comment: in your first select statement, the one without f.key portion, run each select on its own without the union, you will find rows with the same values of date, code, and cost, in your case 4 rows to be exact

Comment: Why are you repeating another answer?

Comment: @DavidAldridge, three answers are the same in concept, but each one have a different value, in my answer, I aim to help the person who asked the question by giving him a reference about Union statements so that he understand it better.   Plus, if you think I repeated the answer, I've added a comment with a clue to the problem right after the first comment, before the question were answered. so I felt it worth adding my answer despite it was correctly answered by that time "two times already"